# Проблема с поиском WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Сделал поиск на сайте стандартным поиском wp.
При поиске записи он её находит, но ссылка там на саму запись. При переходе ничего не даёт. Хотя при выводе записи по ID работает всё нормально. Как подцепить нормальный вывод?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Так сейчас выводит]
[image: так нужно]

1 скрин сейчас, 2 скрин как надо по id записи

Comment: пример вывода прикрепил

Comment: Видимо у вас проблема не с поиском а с постоянными ссылками.

Comment: А каким образом можно проверить результат поиска страница это или запись?

Comment: В вордпрессе есть только смысловое разделение на страницы и  записи. Внутри это всё посттайпы типа post. Я не совсем пониаю зачем вам выяснять "страница" это, либо "запись". Просто правильно настройте постоянные ссылки и проблема устранится.